# How to create a "navicon" effect

Tags: 7, navigation

I would to create a "navicon menu", like in [this article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/08/the-semantic-responsive-design-navicon/).

It seems to be a standard for mobile and responsive sites.
Is there some module that do this?

Comment: Can you explain what navicon is? Or should we read the whole article?

Comment: The "navicon" is a wayu to render a menu in mobile devices. Generally a menu is renderd as an icon that, if I click on it, it expands and show menu links: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/IMG_1990.jpg (the icon on the right)

Comment: I think you're talking about what my team calls a hamburger menu. It's really just a convention for having a special menu display below a certain breakpoint. Any theme or module that supports media queries supports it.

Comment: I was googling for this by the term Sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

The [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module does that. It integrates the Superfish jQuery script into Drupal. It has two responsive menu options for small screens; either rendering it has an accordion or a drop-down. I strongly recommend using the Dev version as it is 'production ready' and has multiple improvements over the older release.